# Enumerating Integers in a Certain Set of Rationals

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be positive integers with $\frac{b}{c}$ reduced. Consider the set of rationals, 
\begin{align}
X(a,b,c) = \left \{ \frac{c(a-k)}{ab} \right \}_{k = 1}^{a-1}.
\end{align}

**Question:** How many integers are in the set $X(a,b,c)$ in terms of $a, b$ and $c$?

For example, there are $\gcd(a,c)-1$ integers in $X(a,1,c)$.

*Edit:* More generally, suppose we consider instead 
\begin{align}
X(a,b,c,e) = \left \{ \frac{c(a-ek)}{ab} \right \}_{i = 1}^{\lceil \frac{a}{e} \rceil - 1}
\end{align}
with $\frac{e}{a}$ reduced. How many integers are in the set $X(a,b,c,e)$ in terms of $a, b, c$ and $e$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $d = ab/\gcd(ab,c)$. Then you just need integers among $(a-k)/d$, $k=1,2,\ldots,a-1$, which is $\lfloor \frac{a-1}{d}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{(a-1)\gcd (ab,c)}{ab} \rfloor$. For $b=1$, this reduces to $\gcd (a,c) - 1$.

If $b/c$ is reduced, then $\gcd (ab,c) = \gcd (a,c)$.

Comment: Thanks! I added a slightly more general scenario to the original question.

Comment: Things get a bit more complicated when you add the variable $e$. You need to find number of $k$ for which $\frac{a-ke}{d}$ is an integer, which is same as solving the linear congruence $ek \equiv a \mod d$. Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) regarding its solutions.